# NSIS - How display a static sidebar image by extending the dialog

Tags: nsis

I hope someone out there can help me with my little problem. Currently, i work on a installer based on NSIS. I know, there is a sidebar image that i can set for welcome and finish page, but i want a sidebar image which is shown the whole time during i switch the pages. The size of the pages shouldnt change, but the dialog must be, for example 92px, bigger in the width to display the image.

My question is, how can i achieve this? By custom pages? A little example would be very nice!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's, like, Wizard97 stuff. Are you developing legacy software?

Answer (score 0):

The sidebar on the welcome and finish pages come from the Modern UI scripts that are part of the NSIS install but it only supports a small header image for the other pages. If you want the sidebar on all pages you have to use something other than the MUI.

Creating your own version is not that hard:

```
InstallDir "$Temp\Example"
AddBrandingImage left 150 2 ; Reserve some space in the UI

LicenseData "${__FILE__}"
Page License
Page Components
Page Directory
Page InstFiles

Function .onGuiInit
InitPluginsDir
File "/oname=$PluginsDir\Wizard.bmp" "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Wizard\win.bmp"
SetBrandingImage /resizetofit "$PluginsDir\Wizard.bmp"
FunctionEnd

Section Hello
SectionEnd
Section World
SectionEnd
```

Depending on the size of your image, this might be all you need, if not then you would have to use [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) on one of the files in %NSIS%\Contrib\UIs and then use `ChangeUI` in your script.

Have you taken a look at some of the 3rd-party NSIS UIs that have been created? [InstallSpiderUI](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/InstallSpiderUI) perhaps?